# Ejecución en Línea AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

He desarrollado una App en AppSheet cuya base de datos reposa en un hoja de cálculo de Google. Mi consulta es: Cuando un usuario al interactuar con la App genera una nueva fila de datos en un tabla de la BD ¿Es posible que a través de un script (al identificar el cambio en la BD) se ejecute automáticamente generando una determinada acción?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 1):

Sí. Deberás usar un activador instalable tipo "change". Este tipo de activador lo puedes crear desde la interfaz de Google Apps Script o bien mediante código.

Estructura básica

```javascript
function respondToChange(e){
   if( /* poner aquí las condiciones */ ){
    // poner aquí lo que quieres que se haga cuando SÍ se cumplan las condiciones
  } else {
    // poner aquí lo que quieres que se haga cuando NO se cumplan las condiciones

  }
}
```

Evita usar nombres reservados para la función a ser llamada por el activador como `onEdit` porque podrías provocar que se ejecute la función por duplicado. Si tu App tendrá varios usuarios insertando filas de forma simultánea, considera usar el Lock Service para prevenir condiciones de carrera.

Recursos

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Para  estos eventos de ejecución automática (por ejemplo, un evento que ejecute una acción cada x horas), ¿requiere que la Hoja de Google este abierta para que el script funcione?

Comment: @MarcosSuarez No.